# Mosaico and 'View in your browser' not working

Tags: 4.6, mosaico

I am running Mosaico beta 1.0 beta1 with 4.6.22 and 'View in your browser' does nothing.  Of course, this is a beta so not surprising.  But... is there a way round this? Otherwise quite impressed with Mosaico after a shaky start, but it would be good to have a greater variety of block shapes to add.  Anyway, for now the above is the problem that I would love to find a workaround for.

Answer (score 1):

In general, bugs with extensions should be reported on the extensions' github page.

In this case, you may be interested to know that there is a new CiviMail/Mosaico extension nearing completion which will supercede the one you are trying out.